# WooCommerce notice message hook for "product removed" and "cart has been updated"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I change the text in `WooCommerce` when my cart has been updated or when a product has been removed? Is there some kind of `add_filter` hook?

Comment: Can you please be more precise, may be using a scenario, thanks. Normally woo commerce have build in these functionalities but you can also create a hook your self for example to update the total when you increment the number of items in your shopping cart. May be with a simple example i can understand better and help.

Comment: @Sigma Well, I want to display the notice "product removed" and "cart updated" in a popup/modal, so I'm looking for methods to customize these messages. It could be a hook or some event listener

Comment: Here is a plugin but may be is not the specific your case but i'm sure give a look to the plugin code to see how it use hooks. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-cart/ or another example you can find here and of course you can change the trigger to open a modal with the info you want to show to final users. https://gist.github.com/mikaelz/f41e29c6a99a595602e4

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to use a plugin. Is there really no hook for this??

Comment: of course you can create the hook yourself or with the help here in SO, i suggest to you the plugin so you can see how is done and try to modify it as your needs. To me sincerely is not so clear the final result you need (sorry in advance), if is possible make a simple scenario explaining the actions of the user and the backend to do to have the result. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, there are three notice types: error, success and notice - but how can I differ if success was deleted or updated? Mehh...really uphill this litlle thing :-/

Comment: Not sure if this still works, but might solve your problem.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124400/woocommerce-how-to-change-cart-updated-message